# How to create unique ID from 3 values <int, int, DateTime>?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm parsing an online feed (tcp relay) that sends approximately 30-50 messages per second (300-500 rows of data). The messages contain 2 types of information: ***orders*** and ***history***.

So, with ***orders***, each one has a unique ID  and I've got:

```
private static Dictionary<long,MarketOrder> MarketOrders = new Dictionary<long,MarketOrder>();
```

to which I insert orders as they come in. Data comes from cache files so messages can contain data which is old and has to be filtered out. I'm currently doing this:

```
if (MarketOrders.ContainsKey(order.OrderID))
{
    // If record exists in a dictionary add hits and overwrite the object if newer.
    int hits = MarketOrders[order.OrderID].Hits;

    if (MarketOrders[order.OrderID].LastUpdated < order.LastUpdated)
    {
        MarketOrders[order.OrderID] = order;
    }

    MarketOrders[order.OrderID].Hits = hits + 1;
}
else
{
    // If not, add new one
    order.Hits = 1;
    MarketOrders.Add(order.OrderID, order);
}
```

This runs in a BackgroundWorker process, and when the dictionary item count hits 2500, it is deep cloned (using binary serializer), cleared and another background process is initiated, that inserts the cloned copy into the database. As soon as dictionary is cleared, orders are being inserted again. So basically I'm trying to receive as much as I can and insert to database in batches.

I'm trying to do something similar with the ***history*** data. There is no unique ID as such and uniqueness comes from combination of `<int, int, DateTime>` values.

I need a fast method of generating a unique key from these 3 values, so I can store it in a dictionary like I do with orders, or another method of storing and filtering that data.

Any suggestions? I'm targeting .NET 4.0.

Comment: Can you not just create a GUID as the unique id or does it have to be created using the int,int, Datatime ?

Comment: Why do you use deep cloning using a serializer? Can't you just create a new `Dictionary` for each batch?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I need to keep unique ID across in-memory list/dict and database. So during the insert I can check if the same row already exists.

Comment: @svick Don't know what to say really, never thought about it. I remember when I was writing this part and I was struggling to clone the list and binary serializer was the fastest way so it ended up in code. Gonna look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Your `DateTime` is not unique?

Comment: @bmewsing No. DateTime is rounded to a day.

Comment: If you get two history entries with the same <int, int, DateTime> combination, is it the same history entry?  Or are all entries you receive unique?

Comment: @tallseth it's going to be the same entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Guid` and use that is the key:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

BitConverter.GetBytes(i1).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
BitConverter.GetBytes(i2).CopyTo(bytes, 4);
BitConverter.GetBytes(dt.Ticks).CopyTo(bytes, 8);

Guid key = new Guid(bytes);
```

Running the above in a loop with a `Dictionary<Guid, int>` vs a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, DateTime>, int>`, the `Guid` key seems to be faster, but you should test it in your scenario.

Just to clarify, I used a `Dictionary<Guid, int>` to test, but in your case it would be a `Dictionary<Guid, YourHistoryType>`.  I wouldn't be surprised if, with everything else going on in your code, any difference between using a `Guid` and `Tuple<int, int, DateTime>` is negligible and you could use whichever feels more appropriate.

Comment: I'll test, and report back with the results. Thanks.

Comment: I ran 5 tests with batches of 10,000 items and Tuple averages at 9.88 sec in code and 6.75 sec in database. Your Guid solution is in fact a little bit faster but like you said, not by a significant amount: 8.80 sec in code and 6.63 sec in database. It's also nicer to deal with than Tuple. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The key of a `Dictionary` doesn't have to be a simple type. In your case, the simplest solution would be to use `Tuple<int, int, DateTime>` as the key. An alternative would be create custom type which correctly implements `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` (and ideally also `IEquatable`).

You can do the same on the database side, most databases support [compound keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key).

Comment: I like the idea of using Tuple as a dictionary key. What's the performance like? I'm especially worried about throwing DateTime around in a key, since I'll be doing a lot of lookups.

Comment: I think performance shouldn't be a problem, `DateTime` is internally just a `ulong`. Though looking the implementation of `Tuple.GetHashCode()`, it seems to box value types, which means a custom class could be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What you think about putting all data into array or some other object and serializing it?

Additionally you can use MD5 alghoritm to pack all of this into string with fixed length.

Comment: I think using CRC is not a good idea. CRC is for error checking, not creating unique values.

Comment: @svick I know that is abusing CRC, but I think its relatively fast and can provide unique short string from quite long binary data. You think MD5 is bad too? Can you explain why? // greetings from Poland :)

Comment: The point is CRC is made for an entirely different purpose, it doesn't even *try* to create a unique string, so it's a terrible idea to use it for that. MD5 is much better, because it is supposed to provide a unique string. But it's still not the best solution here, I think.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about MD5, i added that CRC as alternative. I will fix my answer and remove CRC.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer svick's answer but just to throw it out there how about a nested `Dictionary`? `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<DateTime, object>>>`. Possible? It may allow for fast lookups for collections of items.

Answer (score -2):

What about something like this:

```
int i1 = 123123;
int i2 = 23433;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string s;
s = i1.ToString("X") + i2.ToString("X") + dt.Ticks.ToString();
```

Comment: Without some sort of delimiter, this won't work correctly. And in any case, doing this is not a good practice, `string` is not some sort of “base type” for everything that doesn't fit other primitive types.

Answer (score -2):

The only way in my openion is to do this,

```
DateTime dt = GetYourDateTime();
string uniqueID = dt.Year + "" + dt.Month + "" + dt.Day + "" + dt.Hour + "" + dt.Minute + "" + dt.Second + "" + dt.Millisecond + "";
```

you can then convert it to any numeric types i.e. decimal, long etc

**UPDATED**

```
int a = 2000;
int b = 3000;
DateTime dt = GetYourDateTime();
    string uniqueID = a + "-" + b+ "-" +dt.Year + "" + dt.Month + "" + dt.Day + "" + dt.Hour + "" + dt.Minute + "" + dt.Second + "" + dt.Millisecond + "";
```

For January-11-2013: 2000-3000-2013011100000000

For November-1-2013: 2000-3000-2013110100000000

Comment: i know it is a foolish way to achive something, but may be it help you

Comment: The question asks about a triple `int`, `int`, `DateTime`, not just a `DateTime`. And I don't understand why would such a `string` be a better id than the `DateTime` directly. Besides, in your implementation 11 January and 1 November will have the same id.

Comment: The answer of your first statement in your comment is in your second statement... however i've updated my anser to show you full demo

Comment: Have you tried actually running your code? It does not produce something like `20130111`, but `2013111`. If you format `int` to a `string`, there are not leading zeros by default.